# Trying to return true when the days in February are less than 30

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I am expecting my function to return true when the month is February and the days are less than 30 but it returns false. I can't find the error in my logic because according to my understanding in my code, I checked if(month == 2 && day > 29) to be false. What do I need to do to get it to return true when (month == 2 && day < 30) because when I add an else-if, it returns undefined.

````
function checkDateOfBirth(idNumber) {
  const year = idNumber.substring(0, 2);
  const month = idNumber.substring(2, 4);
  const day = idNumber.substring(4, 6);
  const dateRegex = /^([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]))$/;
  const cutOffDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 2000;
  const fullDate =
    (year > cutOffDate ? "19" : "20") + year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  if (
    day > 31 ||
    month > 12 ||
    (month == 2 && day > 29) ||
    (year % 4 !== 0 && month == 2 && day > 28) ||
    (month == (4 || 6 || 9 || 11) && day > 30) ||
    !dateRegex.test(fullDate)
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}```
````

Comment: Isn't the test "month == February" sufficient? February always has fewer than 30 days. Or are you generally trying to validate the entire date?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it doesn't work? Can you provide some more details like the strings you tested it with? Because when I tried your code it worked as expected:

- 000229 => Produces true
- 000230 => Produces false

Hit the run button below. But maybe I just got your question wrong.

```js
function checkDateOfBirth(idNumber) {
  const year = idNumber.substring(0, 2);
  const month = idNumber.substring(2, 4);
  const day = idNumber.substring(4, 6);
  const dateRegex = /^([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]))$/;
  const cutOffDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 2000;
  const fullDate =
    (year > cutOffDate ? "19" : "20") + year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  console.log("year: " + year);
  console.log("month: " + month);
  console.log("day: " + day);
  console.log("cutOffDate: " + cutOffDate);
  console.log("fullDate: " + fullDate);
  if (
    day > 31 ||
    month > 12 ||
    (month == 2 && day > 29) ||
    (year % 4 !== 0 && month == 2 && day > 28) ||
    (month == (4 || 6 || 9 || 11) && day > 30) ||
    !dateRegex.test(fullDate)
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log("Feb with 29 days valid? " + checkDateOfBirth("000229"))
console.log("Feb with 30 days valid? " + checkDateOfBirth("000230"))
```

Comment: So, I've introduced some unit tests using Jasmine and when I run the tests I get "false" but when log to the console I get true. Here is a snippet of my test:  it("should return true when the month is February and the days are less than 30", function () {
    expect(isIdNumberValid("0002290419089")).toBe(true);
  });

Comment: Why not just utilize date object instead of worrying about leap years and such